# Doctrine2 ManyToMany-relation doesn't save

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a problem with my ManyToMany relation in doctrine2. The relation doesn't persist even though the relation exists. If i check afther the persist in two foreach loops the correct objects are returned.

The first class is Document.

```
class Document extends BaseEntity
{
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Job", mappedBy="documents", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="job_document")
     */
     protected $jobs;
    ....
```

The second class is Job

```
class Job extends BaseEntity
{
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Document", inversedBy="jobs", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="job_document")
     */
    protected $documents;
    ....
```

In my controller I do the following:

```
$job->addDocument($document);
$document->addJob($job);
$em->persist($job);
$em->flush();
```

The add functions work fine. I can see it when I loop through the objects afther I do this.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you only try to update the inverse side and not the owning side of the relationship.

As pointed out in the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html):

> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.
>   Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at
>   least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)

Comment: Some lines above the excerpt I have:

    $em->persist($document);

Comment: @Pino But you have to persist the document after adding the Job.

Comment: I don't think you have to, but I tried it. Same result. The relation isn't saved, both entities are.