# Doctrine2 ManyToMany record not created after deep clone

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have encountered the following problem. The application needs to be able to clone a `Season` entity with all of its related entities. I have inspired in [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158111/deep-clone-doctrine-entity-with-related-entities) - and everything works as it should, but there is a problem with `ManyToMany` relation on the way.

Please take a look at the attached image depicting a small part of the database diagram showing the section I am having problems with.

[image: database diagram segment - many to many relation]

The state I want to achieve is to have *a clone* of a `Price` entity bound to *an existing* `Offer` entity. To put it clear - I cannot and must not clone the `Offer` entity, the new cloned instance of the `Price` entity has to be bound to the same instance the master `Price` entity instance is bound to.

### Example contents of the `offer_price` table before cloning

```
 offer_id | price_id                                                        
----------+----------                                                       
       47 |       77
```

### Intended contents of the `offer_price` table after cloning

```
 offer_id | price_id                                                        
----------+----------                                                       
       47 |       77                                                        
       47 |       79
```

... assuming the `Price` of ID 77 is the master record and the `Price` of ID 79 is the newly cloned instance bound to the same `Offer` record.

## Entity definitions - simplified as possible

### Price

```php
/**                                                                         
 * @Entity                                                                  
 */                                                                         
class Price                                                                 
{                                                                           
    ...                                                                     

    /**                                                                     
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of Offer                
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Offer", mappedBy="prices", cascade={"persist"})
     *                                                                      
     * @get                                                                 
     * @set                                                                 
     * @add                                                                 
     * @remove                                                              
     * @contains                                                            
     */                                                                     
    private $offers;                                                        

    /**                                                                     
     * Class construct                                                      
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __construct()                                           
    {                                                                       
        parent::__construct();                                              
        $this->offers = new ArrayCollection();                              
    }                                                                       


    /**                                                                     
     * Clone entity                                                         
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __clone()                                               
    {                                                                       
        if ($this->getId()) {                                               
            $this->setId(null);                                             
            $this->offers = new ArrayCollection();                          
        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       


    /**                                                                     
     * Add and offer into offers collection                                 
     *                                                                      
     * @param  Offer    $offer                                              
     * @return self                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function addOffer(Offer $offer)                                  
    {
        $this->offers->add($offer);                                         

        return $this;                                                       
    }                                                                       


    ...                                                                     
}
```

### Offer

```php
/**                                                                         
 * @Entity                                                                  
 */                                                                         
class Offer                                                                 
{                                                                           

    ...                                                                     

    /**                                                                     
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of Price                
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Price", inversedBy="offers", cascade={"persist"})
     *                                                                      
     * @get                                                                 
     * @set                                                                 
     * @add                                                                 
     * @remove                                                              
     * @contains                                                            
     */                                                                     
    private $prices;                                                        

    /**                                                                     
     * Class construct                                                      
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __construct()                                           
    {                                                                       
        parent::__construct();                                              
        $this->prices = new ArrayCollection();                              
    }                                                                       

    ...                                                                     
}
```

### Season

```php
/**                                                                         
 * @Entity                                                                  
 */                                                                         
class Season                                                                
{                                                                           

    ...                                                                     

    /**                                                                     
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection of Price                
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Price", mappedBy="season", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *                                                                      
     * @get                                                                 
     * @set                                                                 
     * @add                                                                 
     * @remove                                                              
     * @contains                                                            
     */                                                                     
    private $prices;                                                        

    /**                                                                     
     * Class construct                                                      
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __construct()                                           
    {                                                                       
        parent::__construct();                                              
        $this->prices = new ArrayCollection();                              
    }                                                                       


    /**                                                                     
     * Clone entity                                                         
     *                                                                      
     * @return void                                                         
     */                                                                     
    public function __clone()                                               
    {                                                                       
        if ($this->getId()) {                                               
            $this->setId(null);                                             

            ...                                                             

            $priceClonedCollection = new ArrayCollection();                 
            foreach ($this->prices as $price) {                             
                $priceClone = clone $price;                                 
                $priceClone->setSeason($this);            
                foreach ($price->getOffers() as $offer) {                   
                    $priceClone->addOffer($offer);                          
                }                                                           
                $priceClonedCollection->add($priceClone);                   
            }                                                               
            $this->prices = $priceClonedCollection;                         

            ...                                                             

        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       

    ...                                                                     
}
```

The state I am in is that *I have all objects in a relation I need, but only until the whole set is persisted*. After flushing all the objects by persisting the parent one (`Season`), all the others get cascade persisted as they should *except* the `ManyToMany` binding table, where *no new records are being added*.

The solution I employed in the application so far is quite dirty. After flushing all persisted objects I just iterate over the `Offer` records bound to the `Price` instance (since they are correctly bound to each other) and store all ids which are then being manually inserted into the database. This solution is obviously not ideal and quite fragile.

```php
...                                                                         
/**                                                                         
 * Return an array consisting of mappings that have to be inserted manually 
 *                                                                          
 * @param  Season   $season                                                 
 * @return array                                                            
 */                                                                         
public function getCloneBindingHack(Season $clone)                          
{                                                                           
    foreach ($clone->getPrices() as $price) {                               
        foreach ($price->getOffers() as $offer) {                           
            $bindingHack[] = [                                              
                'offer_id' => $offer->getId(),                              
                'price_id' => $price->getId(),                              
            ];                                                              
        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       

    return $bindingHack ?? [];                                              
}                                                                           
...
```

Therefore I am interested in how to persist relations like this. I presume there is an elegant solution I am just missig as these operations are quite common in real world scenarios. But perhaps Doctrine2 is not able to do this so "You have to do that yourself as Doctrine cannot help you" can also be a valid answer (which would render the ORM quite useless IMHO).

Just to add - in case objects on *both* sides of the `ManyToMany` relation are being newly created and persisted, everything works as it should so I presume the binding table of the `ManyToMany` relation is annotated correctly.

PHP version 7.0.22
Doctrine2 ORM version 2.4.8

Note: I have read this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779669/doctrine2-manytomany-relation-doesnt-save), but it does not address the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem : it is because you don't have link your offer object to your price clone (it is required in the `mappedBy` side). Try something like this :

```
/**                                                                     
 * Clone entity                                                         
 *                                                                      
 * @return void                                                         
 */                                                                     
public function __clone()                                               
{                                                                       
    if ($this->getId()) {                                               
        $this->setId(null);                                             

        ...                                                             

        $priceClonedCollection = new ArrayCollection();                 
        foreach ($this->prices as $price) {                             
            $priceClone = clone $price;                                 
            $priceClone->setSeason($this);            
            foreach ($price->getOffers() as $offer) {
                $offer->addPrice($priceClone);                   
                $priceClone->addOffer($offer);                          
            }                                                           
            $priceClonedCollection->add($priceClone);                   
        }                                                               
        $this->prices = $priceClonedCollection;                         

        ...                                                             

    }                                                                   
}
```

For your ugly part : [this question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158111/deep-clone-doctrine-entity-with-related-entities) and an answer has proposed this [package](https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy)

Comment: I have just tried what you sugested and it worked. I had tried many possibilities without success before, so thanks a lot! - I will now know to handle these situactions in the future.
Just a remark - I know about `DeepCopy`, but I don't want to use it because it is just another unnecessary dependency and because it cannot handle certain situations correctly.
So, thanks again!